# git push (over ssh) hook on remote repo ask for password even if it should not

Tags: git, ssh

What I am trying to accomplish is automatic one way synchronization of 2 bare repos on different machines over ssh.

Pushing from one bare repo [CENTRAL machine] to another bare repo on other machine [REDMINE machine] like this:

1. on workstation [WS] I (or any of my colleague) push to bare repo on central server [CENTRAL]
2. there is triggered *post-update* hook [CENTRAL] which should do `git push` to another bare repo [REDMINE] under user `'lamparna'` (which have access to REDMINE with keys)

The complication is, that I push on WS -> CENTRAL as `'foton'` and hooked push have to be done as `'lamparna'` (CENTRAL -> REDMINE).

post-update hook [on CENTRAL]:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
# post-receive
`sudo -u lamparna git push --mirror ssh://lamparna@REDMINE/home/lamparna/repos/git/jine/lamparna.git`
```

I already manage it to work on "imitating push" (according to http://krisjordan.com/essays/setting-up-push-to-deploy-with-git ):

on [WS]

```
ssh CENTRAL  'cd /opt/git_repos/jine/lamparna.git && echo "$FROM_COMIT_HASH $TO_COMIT_HASH" | /opt/git_repos/jine/lamparna.git/hooks/post-update'
```

This will run correctly, no password needed.
But when I do a real push: `git push`, then pushing on CENTRAL is done, hook is triggered, but end with:

```
 remote: sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Surrounding:
On CENTRALL I allowed all users from group `sitd` to run git as `lamparna` without password:

```
%sitd ALL=(lamparna) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/git_push_to_lamparna.sh, /usr/bin/git
```

Comment: `Defaults:your_user !requiretty` in `/etc/sudoers` should help you

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. Tried: `Defaults:lamparna !requiretty` and  `Defaults !requiretty`

Comment: I found answer in 'duplicated' question:  I have to use  `sudo -u lamparna /usr/bin/git push --mirror ssh://lamparna@REDMINE/home/lamparna/repos/git/jine/lamparna.git` to work without password.  Difference is `git push` vs `/usr/bin/git push` .